# Is there a way to connect to Gerrit server from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, gerrit

I am trying to create a pipeline in azure devOps which gets triggered when I checkin my codes in Gerrit server repo. I tried with a service connection of 'Other Git' option. But no luck. The pipeline is refusing to identify it as a git repository. Is there a way to achieve it?

Below is the log:
***remote: Unauthorized
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git**.*******.***/**/***/MY_REPO.git/'
##[error]Git fetch failed with exit code: 128***

Comment: `The pipeline is refusing to identify it as a git repository. ` Could you please explain this point?  `Other Git` option supports http/ https URL. Generally, the Gerrit server url is http. Based on my test, I could create the service connection.  What kind of repo is yours(Git or TFVC)? You could share the screenshot about the current issue.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT I have updated the question. These are the final lines of my log. Its repeatative lines, so only pasted this much.

Comment: From the error log, it seems that the URL is valid. But the authrentication is failed.  What method did you use for repo authentication ?  You could check if you could git clone in your local machine with the same method.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT I am using SSH to checkout to my local system. I recently tried the Jenkins pipeline(local) where I used 'Username and PrivateKey' and that worked. Can we do something similar in azure devOps. Does SSH task helps here? Right Now I am trying to figure that out.

Comment: It seems that the other git service connection doesn't support setting Private SSH key as password. You could try to directly use **Username and Password** to connect the Repo. On the other hand, the ssh task is running after the checkout step, so it will not help to connect the repo.